# Need a decent alternative to define json interface in web3.eth.Contract function

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I created a file called contract.js with the abi code as follows.

```
var contract_abi = [{
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_serviceproducerDescription",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "retrieveProducerView",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
{...}, 
{...},
]
```

and trying to use it in app.js file

```
var contract = require("./contract.js");
var PublishServiceContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.contract_abi,"0x..");
```

If i try to read this way, I get the below error.

> Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when
>   instantiating a contract object.

But it works fine if I use the total abi I get from remix in this call

```
var PublishServiceContract = new web3.eth.Contract([{...},{...},{...}],"0x..");
```

I don't understand the difference between the two and reason for failure. Can someone help me please.

Thanks!!!

Comment: What does `console.log(contract)` say? Probably, you haven't exported it correctly.

Comment: @someart it returns an empty {}

Comment: Any idea why it returns an empty paranthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've understood from comments, you haven't exported the code correctly. Either you can store your ABI in `.json` file, or if you want to store it as a `.js` file then you have to set the `contract_abi` value to `module.exports`.

So you can simply do `module.exports = contract_abi` at the last line of your ABI file.

Comment: Hi, i added module.exports = contract_abi in the contract.js file. but still console.log(contract.contract_abi) returns undefined.

Comment: You should use just `contract` variable directly now

Comment: It said contract_abi is not defined. thats why I used in the earlier form.

Comment: You've probably haven't understood me.

You should just do `var contract = require('./contract.js')` and use `contract` variable which will have the value of `contract_abi` variable from `./contract.js` file.

Comment: If you want it ti be `contract.contract_abi` then you will need to do `module.exports = { contract_abi }`

Comment: @someart It worked. Thanks a lot. I never used module.exports before. so a bit confused before.

Answer (score 1):

Making the following changes while passing ABI to instantiate contract worked for me.

Changed from

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
```

to

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(contractABI),contractAddress);
```